# Reading in a large file

Tags: c++, input, maps, streaming

I have to read in a large file, character by character, and put each character in a `map` with a corresponding key. My question is, is there a way to read in the file to the `map` and save it there, so the program doesn't have to read the whole file character by character each time (takes forever)? 
The characters are used later in the program to do an encode/decode thing.

Comment: in what problem read *all or partial* file in buffer first and then put each character in a map with a corresponding key ?

Comment: How do you create the key for each char?

Comment: I'm using a multimap, put the character in the key and then the line number and position in each line as a vector of ints for the association

Comment: Maybe you can save the map in another file, so you don't have to recreate it every time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, ir gonna take forever, but you can use a `std::unordered_multimap` to speed it up a little, by skipping the sort phase.